# Floor Makes Metal Clang When Walked On - One Room

Tags: floor, subfloor, noise

We have a 3 bedroom, 2 bathroom house. The whole house has hard-wood flooring. One bedroom on the corner of the house has a floor that sounds hollow... When walked on it makes a loud clanging sound... As if noise is vibrating through a duct or pipe. This sound travels to the living room which is across the house, and seems to come from the walls there.

Our heating/AC is heat pump and the ducts are run in the ceiling. The floor seems level. No other floor in the house has this problem. What is causing this noise and how do I fix it?

Also, this house is in Florida and off-grade with a crawlspace.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @proteus yup, it was old HVAC ductwork that was strapped to the floor joists and rattling. Had a contractor crawl under there and cut it all down + haul off and problem has been gone ever since!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was due to was old HVAC duct-work that was strapped to the floor joists and rattling. Had a contractor crawl under there and cut it all down + haul off and problem has been gone ever since!